# Is there a way I can loop through rows in a dataframe where the cell values are equal to a certain value?

Tags: r, loops

| Column1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 10 | 20 |
| 10 | 20 |

Is there a way to do a for loop through rows where the cell value in Column 2 is 20 only?

Comment: Can you show the expected ouptut  You can subset i.e. `subset(df1, Column2 == 20)`

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want ?

```
df=as.data.frame(cbind(Column1=c(20,20,20,20,10,10),Column2=c(0,0,0,0,20,20)))

for(i in which(df$Column2==20)){print(df$Column1[i])}
   [1] 10
   [1] 10
```